# binary search question

Tags: binary-search

For binary search, what is the average number of comparisons needed to find a record in a file?

Comment: It's related to homework.  So what?

Comment: so if the point was for you to figure it out yourself, no one here wants to help you cheat.

Comment: The question is strange, since you don't generally binary search a file. If you have data in a file that you want binary searched, you would generally read it into memory first, then do a binary search, making it irrelevant that the thing being searched is a file. If you're trying to search a file that is to large to be read into memory, binary search isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is homework, so I'll provide a hint instead of a straight-up answer.  I'll also assume you've been asked to find a relatively exact answer, not just a big-O answer.

Think of it this way:  Every time you do a comparison, you halve the search space.  If the search space is of size S, then the probability of finding the record on the next iteration is 1/S.  If C denotes the number of comparisons, then P(find it on comparison C) = P(don't find it in < C comparisons) * P(find it on comparison C | don't find it in < C comparisons).

Comment: Thanks, a big-O answer is meaningless.  I think your answer won't help though because it's about probability.  I don't need the probability I need the number.

Comment: But how would you calculate the average without using probability?  The average is just the sum of all possible values of C, weighted by their probability.  That said, I haven't fully worked out the math but I can tell it would be fairly messy if I did.  This is a pretty evil problem, especially if your professor is a stickler for exact derivations as opposed to approximations.

Comment: Also, my gut feeling is that you've misunderstood the problem and you should ask for clarification.  Find out whether you really need an **exact** answer, and if not, whether it needs to only be asymptotically correct or correct for every N.  If it has to be exact for every N, it's so horribly messy as to be virtually impossible.